# Add a trendline to a barchart with xlswriter

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am trying to create a bar chart with a trendline. I can do this in excel and would like to automate the process. xlswriter is pretty easy to use and I have replicated the bar chart it is just the trend line that does not work for me. It seems to add 2 elements the line and an additional bar on the top of each stack.

[image: charts]

This is the code to create the chart on the left

```
import xlsxwriter

# create worbook, workseet and chart
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Example.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

# Add the worksheet data
headings = ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Capacity']
data = [
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
    [20, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30]
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$A$1',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})

chart1.add_series({
    'name':      '=Sheet1!$C$1',
    'values':    '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7',
    'trendline': {'type': 'linear'},
})

# Set an Excel chart style.
chart1.set_style(11)

# Add a chart title
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'xlsxwriter chart'})

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('F1', chart1)

# Finally, close the Excel file
workbook.close()
```

The bars select the data I am trying to insert as a trend line. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "It seems to add 2 elements the line and the additional highlighted bars." What do you mean by that? It isn't clear what issue you are having. Could you explain a bit more.

Comment: In the picture there is a black line that goes from 18 to maybe 9. There are also grey bars that are stacked on top each with a size of 7. There should be a horizontal line at 7 on the vertical axis.

Comment: added a picture of what I was expecting without the extra bar and diagonal trend line

Comment: The bars are all 7 and when you click on them they are what was intended from the code 'values':   f"='{chartSheetName}'!$I${row}:$AQ${row}"

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough information there to figure out what your issue is or how to fix it. It looks like you are adding a series to a stacked column chart with a trendline. Try create a smaller complete working example that demonstrates the issue and ask the question again.

Comment: Sorry, I was hoping my issue was simple. The full example should help.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you are trying to do is to add a secondary line chart rather than a trendline. You can do this with the XlsxWriter [chart.combine()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/chart.html#chart-combine) method.

Like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

# create worbook, workseet and chart
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("Example.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'column', 'subtype': 'stacked'})

# Add the worksheet data
headings = ['Model 1', 'Model 2', 'Capacity']
data = [
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
    [20, 30, 40, 40, 30, 30]
]

worksheet.write_row('A1', headings)
worksheet.write_column('A2', data[0])
worksheet.write_column('B2', data[1])
worksheet.write_column('C2', data[2])

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$A$1',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7',
})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series({
    'name':       '=Sheet1!$B$1',
    'values':     '=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7',
})


# Add a chart title
chart1.set_title ({'name': 'xlsxwriter chart'})

# Create a second line chart.
chart2 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'line'})

chart2.add_series({
    'name':      '=Sheet1!$C$1',
    'values':    '=Sheet1!$C$2:$C$7',
})


# Combine the charts.
chart1.combine(chart2)

# Insert the chart into the worksheet (with an offset).
worksheet.insert_chart('F1', chart1)

# Finally, close the Excel file
workbook.close()
```

**Output**:

[image]